# Getting controller name from a request.referer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I know I can use `request.referrer` to get the full referrer URL in Rails, but is there a way to just get the controller name from the URL?

I want to see if the URL of http://myurl.com/profiles/2 includes "profiles"

I know I can use a regex to do it but I wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: it does not seem to be a right approach at all. What if some other server is the referrer?

Comment: Please @tvalent2, reselect the correct answer. The upvotes speak by themselves.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Inside the controller, you have the method `controller_name` which returns you only the name. In your case, it would return "profiles".
You may also use `params[:controller]` which returns the same string.

Comment: Isn't this question incorrectly accepted? Did he not want to know how to decompose the action/controller of the referrer and not the current action's?

Comment: I can delete my answer if it isn't correct but as far as i remember it worked perfectly

Answer (score 109):

Keep in mind that `request.referrer` gives you the url of the request before the current one. That said, here is how you can convert `request.referrer` to controller/actionn information:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)
```

it should give you something like

```
{:subdomain => "", :controller => "x", :action => "y"}
```

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)[:controller]` to be precise.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my try which works with Rails 3 & 4. This code extracts one parameter on logout and redirects user to customized login page otherwise it redirects to general login page.
You can easily extract `:controller` this way. Controller part:

```
def logout
  auth_logout_user
  path = login_path
  begin
    refroute = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)
    path = subscriber_path(refroute[:sub_id]) if refroute && refroute[:sub_id]
  rescue ActionController::RoutingError
    #ignore
  end
  redirect_to path
end
```

And tests are important as well:

```
test "logout to subscriber entry page" do
  session[:uid] = users(:user1).id
  @request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = "http://host/s/client1/p/xyzabc"
  get :logout
  assert_redirected_to subscriber_path('client1')
end

test "logout other referer" do
  session[:uid] = users(:user1).id
  @request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = "http://anyhost/path/other"
  get :logout
  assert_redirected_to login_path
end

test "logout with bad referer" do
  session[:uid] = users(:user1).id
  @request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = "badhost/path/other"
  get :logout
  assert_redirected_to login_path
end
```

Comment: woot woot for TDD on an answer!